# SDTT throws error that logo's url is required for the publisher

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I am building a `BlogPosting` schema and need to supply a `publisher` as one of the properties.

The publisher bit reads as:

```json
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "MyOrganization",
    "image": "https://uat.mydomain.com/media/1267/logo-main.png",
    "logo": "https://uat.mydomain.com/media/1267/logo-main.png"
  }
```

However it throws the error on the `publisher` object the `logo` property:

> `https://uat.mydomain.com/media/1267/logo-main.png` (A value for the `url` field is required.)

I seriously don't know what it expect other than an URI, as `Organization`'s `logo` is supposed to be of type `URL` or `ImageObject` so I supplied an URI: https://schema.org/Organization and an URI cannot have a `url` property.

I'm using Schema.NET and this compiles without a problem.

Comment: While the duplicate question uses a different syntax (Microdata instead of JSON-LD), the issue is only with the use of the vocabulary (Schema.org), no matter which syntax is used.